# Pass parameter to U-SQL Partition function

Tags: u-sql, azure-data-factory

We want to pass a parameter to U-SQL from Azure Data Factory v2 in order to control our level of parallelism in ADLA.

I, therefore, have the parameter `@USQL_Parallelism` that I pass from ADF.

How do I best integrate that in my script?

```
@CompleteExtractClean = 
    SELECT
        [CE].[FileName],
        [CE].[iDocId],
        XXX
    FROM @CompleteExtract AS [CE]
    OPTION(PARTITION(iDocId)=(PARTITIONCOUNT=@USQL_Parallelism));
```

I now get the following error:

> Invalid syntax found in the script.

What's the syntax to correctly handle the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

were you using ADFv2 UI tool? If so, please follow the below picture to pass value to "USQL_Parallelism".

[image]
if you were using Powershell or Rest API to run U-SQL activity, please add the following code in "typeProperties" part in pipeline json.

```
"parameters": {
  "USQL_Parallelism": "1"  // the value you need
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your comment.
I am using ADF v2, and pass the USQL_Parallelism as a parameter.

I guess myself the issue is in the U-SQL code itself, where I pass the parameter.  

OPTION(PARTITION(iDocId)=(PARTITIONCOUNT=@USQL_Parallelism));

I think I need to quote around the parameter and the rest of the line.  But how exactly I haven't found yet :-)

Comment: all right, not sure whether these two links give you any clues: https://causewaysolutions.com/executing-u-sql-scripts-azure-data-factory-v2/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/variables/using-variables . Thanks.